# Scheduling to reduce average work (Algorthm/Not thread scheduling)

Tags: algorithm, schedule

I think there is an existing algorithm for just this problem, but I am having trouble finding it

Basically, I have an amount of work, and a due day, and I want to find the schedule that creates the lowest amount of work per day

For example, if I have one job that will take 3hrs and is due on day 3, and another job that will take 2 hrs and is due on day 5

I want to create the schedule where you work 1hr per day (aka work on job 1 for first 3 days, and two hrs the next)

```
Right Now my program schedules this as:
Day   : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-----------------------------
Job 1 : 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
Job 2 : .2| .2| .2| .2| .2|
Total :1.2|1.2|1.2| .2| .2|
Worked:1&2|1&2|1&2|1&2|1&2| //What job was worked on

But I want it to schedule it as
Day   : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
-----------------------------
Job 1 : 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
Job 2 : 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
Total : 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
Worked: 1 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 2 | //What job was worked on
```

What algorithm would create the second schedule?

*Work to Show*

I honestly can't think of a place to start besides brute-forcing it

Answer (score 0):

An optimization problem such as this has 3 components:

- Decision variables (in Day d how much do I work on Job j etc...)
- Objective function: minimize variance of daily work hours
- Constraints: Job 1 must have X hours completed by day 3, etc

Look into quadratic programming for this (the variance function is quadratic).